# Set git upstream on feature branch automatically?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

Many times at work I'll check out a branch and then i'll do a `git pull` to check things. I'll then be promped with a message like so

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature-branch-111
```

I then usually do the latter option which looks like

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature-branch-111 feature-branch-111`

at which time I can do a `git pull` and it works.

But I get tired of doing this with each and every branch. Is there a way to have git just assume the branches are the same name? or maybe another way to make this easier?

Comment: Don't bother using branches. If you want to look at "their" `feature-branch-111`, just look at `origin/feature-branch-111`. That's your Git's name for their feature-branch. This is a *remote-tracking name* rather than a *branch* name, so to switch to that commit you must allow Git to use "detached HEAD" mode, but if you're just going to *look*, rather than create new commits, that's fine.

Comment: Note that running `git fetch` updates all your remote-tracking names, after which you can just use them. You don't even have to check them out, you can just run `git log` or `git show` on the remote-tracking name.

Comment: The simple way to remember all this is: *Git does not **need** branches. Branches, in Git, are there to make your life easier. When they're not doing that, don't use them.*

Comment: These are all comments because there's a simple answer to the question you asked, and this isn't the answer to the question you asked. :-) The answer to what you asked is to use `branch.autoSetupMerge` or `branch.autoSetupRebase`.